# many to many insert php and database architecture

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am doing a database for a project and im stuck in a point.

Since every product can have multiple field of use, but even every materials can have multiple field of use, i come up with that solution.

THis is my database architecture.

http://i57.tinypic.com/2mhc03o.jpg

product are specifical for every material e.g. there can't be the same product for 2 material

material are leather, simil-leather, cloth, PVC

field of use are the field which that material can be used: sport, leisure, work

The problem is that material can be used in many field and many field can be used for a material, so it's N:M

Every product can be used in many field and many field can be used for a product so it's too N:M

For example, leather can be used in work, sport,  cloth in work sport and office

product can be used in some or all field of application and vice versa.

1)WIth my architecture, to retrieve a material that can be used in a specific field of use i need to do 4 JOIN between all the table. Is it ok? or it's too long?

2)Also, when the user want to add a new category, to insert which field of use that category can have, i need to have a product already for that category.

3)when i want to fill a many to many relationship, i need to do it manually in the conjuction table (field_of_use_product) with some php codes right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need three joins for four tables that involved.
2. No, product may insert after all of the data at foreign tables have inserted.
3. Yes, it's a simple insert if you know the foreign keys.